# (OpcNetApi) Ex_Network_Error Could not connect to the server. when trying to connect locally

Tags: c#, .net, opc

I complied my c# application with 64bits and deployed on 64bit process server machine. In the same machine the opc server is installed. when i try to connect the opc server locally, it throws me error "Could not connect to the server".

do i need to do necessary setting even if i want to use locally?
does anyone have idea? please help

Comment: Did you mean E_NETWORK_ERROR ? Which function throws the exception or gives the error? If it is an exception, what is the call stack? Does it also happen when you compile your application for 32 bits?

Comment: yes its E_NETWORK_ERROR. it works fine when i run on 32bits. but not on 64bits processor.

Comment: Unless you already have done so, try installing the x64 version of OPC Core Components from the OPC Foundation (https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/developer-kits-classic/core-components/ ). Most OPC Servers are 32-bit, and do not care about someone connecting to them from the 32-bit world; they "forget" to install the proper version of the Core Components (which includes OPCEnum and proxies/stubs) in the 64-bit environment.

Comment: Installing 64-bit core components does not solve problem, I did DCOM configurations in the opc server, given "anonymous_logon" and "everyone" users and it works.